# Use ''of'' and ''for''

Tags: british-english

What is the correct sentence?

> I am attaching invoice for this order.
>   *or*
>   I am attaching invoice of this order.

Answer (score 0):

Both "of" and "for" are correct, but even in simplified writing (as is the case with emails of a commercial nature), "of"-phrases will need the noun preceding them to have a article.

While the normal -- grammatical -- way in which both sentences should be written is:

- I am attaching **the** invoice for this order.
- I am attaching **the** invoice of this order.

if the writer decides, for economy reasons, to eliminate the article, "for" will sound better than "of", for the reason mentioned at the beginning.

Actually, "for" may sound more idiomatic in any case.